# Accessing a Dictionary Using Get

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, get

> For this problem assume the following assignment statement has been executed.
>
> ```
> weekdays = {'Sunday':0, 'Monday':1, 'Tuesday':2, 'Wednesday':3,
>             'Thursday':4, 'Friday':5, 'Saturday':6}
> ```
>
> Assume the variable `day` contains a value that may or may not be the name of a day. Write an assignment statement using get that assigns to `day_num` the day number if `day` contains the name of a day and `-1` otherwise.
>
> For example, if day is `'Wednesday'` then `day_num` should be `3` and if `day` is `'Talk Like a Pirate Day'` then `day_num` should be `-1`.

Here is my code:

```
day_num = weekdays.get(day)
if day_num==None:
   day_num=-1
```

I just don't understand why is it still wrong; it is correct I think. The homework system keeps on showing

> You should use only one assignment statement (and nothing else)

Answer (score 1):

You are using two assignment statements. Perhaps you should give [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) a **second** argument:

```
day_num = weekdays.get(day, -1)
```

That second argument is a default to return if `day` is not present in the dictionary; the default default is `None` but here I return `-1` instead.

This saves you a test for `is None` and a second assignment.